# unable to use hover on visible overflow content

Tags: jquery, css, hover, overflow, jquery-hover

Unfortunately I find myself trying to work around a layout that doesn't exactly support my needs.  That said, changing it totally is not currently an option.

That said, I basically have some overflow content that I have set overflow:visible on with also a white-space:nowrap.  This basically acts like a column span.

here is a  [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D639t/1/)

and since SO requires it, here is some sample code.

the html:

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='third'>one</div>
<div class='third'>two</div>
<div class='third'>three</div>
</div>
<div class='container'>
<div class='third overflow'>this is some really long <a> hover </a></div>
<div class='third'>&nbsp;</div>
<div class='third'>has to align w/ three</div>
</div>
```

the css:

```
div {float:left;}
div.third {width: 33%;}
div.container {width: 400px;overflow:hidden;}
div.overflow { overflow:visible; white-space:nowrap;}
a {color: green;font-weight:bold;}
a:hover {color: red; }
```

the js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('div.overflow a').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    alert('mouse enter');
});

$('div.overflow a').bind('hover', function() {
    alert('hover');
});
/* just to prove it is wired up */
$('div.overflow a').trigger('hover');});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **1st** problem is not the overflow, but the fact that the following `.third` element is on top of it and it *absorbs* the mouse events..

To resolve this add `position:relative` and `z-index:999` on the `div.overflow a` element.

The **2nd** problem is that the `hover` is not an event. It is a shortcut to the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

So you need to use it in the following way (*note that it will fire for both enter and leave*)

```
$('div.overflow a').hover(function() {
    alert('hover');
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/D639t/3/ (*using `console.log` instead of `alert`*)

Comment: thank you.  I had tried the z-index thing, but was missing the position relative piece.  The hover jquery stuff was on the fly demonstration that I didn't really care about.